# How can I use Rails newer `validates :column, presence: value` syntax inside of a `validate` block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my `Applicant` model.

```rb
validate do |applicant|
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

This works, but Rubocop complains:

> Rails/Validation: Prefer the new style validations `validates :column, presence: value` over `validates_presence_of`.

However, when I change things to:

```rb
validate do |applicant|
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Rails falls over and throws the following error:

> undefined method `validates` for `#<Applicant:0x00007ff17f7d7a58>` Did you mean? validate validate! valid_date? _validators

How can I use the newer `validates :column, presence: value` syntax inside of my `validate` block?

**Edit**:

I'm using a `validate` block, as I want to pass params to a custom validation method, like so:

```
validate do |applicant|
  validates :name, presence: true
  applicant.validate_stuff(param1, param2)
end

def validate_stuff(param1, param2)
  # return something
end
```

Am I missing a better way to do that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you use the newer syntax outside the `validate` block? I haven't ever found myself needing to use a `validate` block the way you're doing it, so perhaps I'm missing an important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I'm using the `validate` block because I want to pass parameters to one of my custom validation methods. Would you know a way to pass params to a custom validation method using the newer syntax? I just updated my question with details.

Comment: How about you just leave that "standard" validation outside the block? Again, just thinking out loud - apologies if not helpful.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @jvillian. Unless there's a specific requirement for the name's presence to be checked inside the custom `validate` block, it could be placed outside it and the `validate` block could accept parameters and call `validate_stuff`.

Comment: Lol, that's the problem of oversimplifying the question, I guess. I'm afraid that in reality, the `validates :name, presence: true` is inside the `validate_stuff` method. I'd like to keep it there if poss, as it is used to dynamically validate three (almost) identical sections of my form.